# How to get rid from clamd process eating 62% of the memory

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I've searched around and saw a few similar questions and I do not find a successful answer.

I have read that this is Clamav antivirus, I installed Mailcow, and there said I should change in mailcow.conf the skip_clamav set to y, I'v done it but didn't work.

How can I get rid of it? I have tried even to kill the process by using pkill clamd, it killed and immediately return back.

How to find which is running this process and to kill it?

Tried:
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon stop

Says command is not recognized

[View process list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBsGT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can:
uninstall `clamav-daemon` package
**OR**
stop `clamd` service and disable its automatic startup - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498644/2139766